# What is the proper term for the abbreviation of a team name?

Tags: terminology

I've been working with a group to make a custom website for displaying player and team information for an e-sports league, and in my table columns I've been using "Team Abbreviation" for the heading where a team's three-letter abbreviation is displayed, e.g. `CHI` or `SFC`.

Is there a proper term for this designation?

Comment: I believe the NYSE uses the term *symbol* for its four-letter codes.

Comment: The New York Stock Exchange is not a "team". Team initials.

Comment: I would just call it the Team Code unless that term means something else.

Comment: The International Olympic Committee uses three-letter codes for countries which are known as "country codes", so "team code" seems logical. Or just abbreviation, code, etc. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_IOC_country_codes